# Huffman encoding implementation for Unicode

Tags: rust, compression

I'm looking for a general review with emphasis on idiomaticness and error handling.

```
extern crate byteorder;
extern crate rand;

use std::collections::hash_map::HashMap;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

use byteorder::{ReadBytesExt, WriteBytesExt, NativeEndian};
use std::{fmt, error, result, io, path, cmp, fs};
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;


type Result<T> = result::Result<T, HuffmanError>;
const BITS: usize = 8;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum HuffmanError {
    Io(io::Error),
    ParseTree,
    AlphabetMismatch,
    Empty,
}

impl fmt::Display for HuffmanError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use HuffmanError::*;
        use std::error::Error;
        match *self {
            Io(ref err) => write!(f, "IO error: {}", err),
            ParseTree => write!(f, "Parse tree error: {}", self.description()),
            Empty => write!(f, "Empty error: {}", self.description()),
            AlphabetMismatch => write!(f, "Alphabet mismatch error: {}", self.description()),
        }
    }
}

impl error::Error for HuffmanError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        use HuffmanError::*;
        match *self {
            Io(ref err) => err.description(),
            ParseTree => "invalid encoded huffman tree",
            AlphabetMismatch => "alphabet doesn't match parsed tree",
            Empty => "empty stream",
        }
    }
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&error::Error> {
        match *self {
            HuffmanError::Io(ref err) => Some(err),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl From<io::Error> for HuffmanError {
    fn from(err: io::Error) -> HuffmanError {
        HuffmanError::Io(err)
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, Debug)]
enum HuffmanTree {
    Inner {
        frecuency: u32,
        left: Box<HuffmanTree>,
        right: Box<HuffmanTree>,
    },
    Leaf { frecuency: u32, character: char },
}

fn characters_mode(file: &str) -> HashMap<char, u32> {
    let mut table = HashMap::new();
    for c in file.chars() {
        *(table.entry(c).or_insert(0)) += 1;
    }
    table
}

fn create_priority_queue(input: &str) -> BinaryHeap<HuffmanTree> {
    characters_mode(input)
        .iter()
        .map(|(c, f)| {
            HuffmanTree::Leaf {
                character: *c,
                frecuency: *f,
            }
        })
        .collect()
}

impl HuffmanTree {
    fn new(input: &str) -> Result<HuffmanTree> {
        let mut pq = create_priority_queue(input);
        for _ in 1..pq.len() {
            let min1 = pq.pop().unwrap();
            let min2 = pq.pop().unwrap();
            pq.push(min1.join(min2));
        }
        pq.pop().ok_or(HuffmanError::Empty)
    }

    fn frec(&self) -> u32 {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match self {
            &Inner { frecuency, .. } |
            &Leaf { frecuency, .. } => frecuency,
        }
    }

    fn join(self, other: HuffmanTree) -> HuffmanTree {
        HuffmanTree::Inner {
            frecuency: self.frec() + other.frec(),
            left: Box::new(self),
            right: Box::new(other),
        }
    }

    fn create_char_mapper_recur(&self,
                                bit_vec: &mut BitVector,
                                map: &mut HashMap<char, BitVector>) {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match self {
            &Inner { ref left, ref right, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(true);
                left.create_char_mapper_recur(bit_vec, map);
                bit_vec.push(false);
                right.create_char_mapper_recur(bit_vec, map);

            }
            &Leaf { character, .. } => {
                map.insert(character, bit_vec.clone());
            }
        }
        bit_vec.pop();
    }

    fn create_char_mapper(&self) -> HashMap<char, BitVector> {
        let mut bit_vec = BitVector::new();
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        if let &HuffmanTree::Leaf { .. } = self {
            bit_vec.push(true);
        }
        self.create_char_mapper_recur(&mut bit_vec, &mut map);
        map
    }

    fn decode<I, T>(encoded_walk: &mut I, mut chars: &mut T) -> Result<HuffmanTree>
        where I: Iterator<Item = bool>,
              T: Iterator<Item = char>
    {
        match encoded_walk.next() {
            Some(x) if x => {
                let left = Self::decode(encoded_walk, chars)?;
                let right = Self::decode(encoded_walk, chars)?;
                Ok(left.join(right))
            }
            Some(_) => {
                let c = chars.next()
                    .ok_or(HuffmanError::AlphabetMismatch)?;
                Ok(HuffmanTree::Leaf {
                    frecuency: 0,
                    character: c,
                })
            }
            None => Err(HuffmanError::ParseTree),
        }
    }

    fn serialize<W: std::io::Write>(&self, writer: &mut W) -> Result<()> {
        let (encoded_walk, alphabet) = self.encode();

        let walk_bit_len = encoded_walk.len() as u64;
        writer.write_u64::<NativeEndian>(walk_bit_len)?;
        writer.write(&encoded_walk.bits)?;

        let encoded_alphabet = alphabet.as_bytes();
        let alphabet_byte_len = encoded_alphabet.len() as u64;
        writer.write_u64::<NativeEndian>(alphabet_byte_len)?;
        writer.write_all(encoded_alphabet)?;

        Ok(())
    }

    fn de_serialize<R: std::io::Read>(reader: &mut R) -> Result<HuffmanTree> {
        use std::io::Read;

        let walk_len = reader.read_u64::<NativeEndian>()?;
        let mut walk_bytes = Vec::new();
        reader.take((walk_len + BITS as u64 - 1) / BITS as u64)
            .read_to_end(&mut walk_bytes)?;

        let bit_vec = BitVector {
            bits: walk_bytes,
            size: walk_len as usize,
        };

        let chars_len = reader.read_u64::<NativeEndian>()?;
        let mut chars = String::new();
        reader.take(chars_len)
            .read_to_string(&mut chars)?;

        let bit_iter = &mut bit_vec.iter();
        Self::decode(bit_iter, &mut chars.chars())

    }

    fn encode_recur(&self, bit_vec: &mut BitVector, alphabet: &mut String) {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match self {
            &Inner { ref left, ref right, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(true);
                left.encode_recur(bit_vec, alphabet);
                right.encode_recur(bit_vec, alphabet);
            }
            &Leaf { character, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(false);
                alphabet.push(character);
            }
        }
    }

    fn encode(&self) -> (BitVector, String) {
        let mut bit_vector = BitVector::new();
        let mut alphabet = String::new();
        self.encode_recur(&mut bit_vector, &mut alphabet);
        (bit_vector, alphabet)
    }

    fn encode_string(&self, file_str: &str) -> BitVector {
        let char_map = self.create_char_mapper();
        let itr = file_str.chars()
            .map(|c| char_map.get(&c).expect("Assertion error"));

        let mut bit_vec = BitVector::new();
        for code in itr {
            bit_vec.append(&code);
        }
        bit_vec
    }

    fn decode_string<I>(&self, bit_iter: I) -> String
        where I: Iterator<Item = bool>
    {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        let mut node = self;
        let mut output = String::new();
        for bit in bit_iter {
            if let &Inner { ref left, ref right, .. } = node {
                node = if bit { left } else { right }
            }
            if let &Leaf { character, .. } = node {
                output.push(character);
                node = self;
            }
        }
        output
    }
}

impl Ord for HuffmanTree {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> cmp::Ordering {
        self.frec().cmp(&other.frec()).reverse()
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for HuffmanTree {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> Option<cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for HuffmanTree {
    fn eq(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> bool {
        self.frec() == other.frec()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct BitVector {
    bits: Vec<u8>,
    size: usize,
}

impl BitVector {
    fn new() -> BitVector {
        BitVector {
            bits: Vec::new(),
            size: 0,
        }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, bit: bool) {
        let leftover = self.size % BITS;
        if leftover == 0 {
            self.bits.push(0);
        }
        let last_byte = self.bits
            .last_mut()
            .expect("Assertion error");

        *last_byte |= (bit as u8) << leftover;
        self.size += 1;
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) {
        if self.len() == 0 {
            return;
        }
        let len = self.size - 1;
        self.put(len, false);
        self.size = len;
        if self.len() % BITS == 0 {
            self.bits.pop();
        }
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    fn push_all(&mut self, bits: &[bool]) {
        for bit in bits {
            self.push(*bit);
        }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, other: &BitVector) {
        let leftover = self.size % BITS;
        let empty_bits = BITS - leftover;
        let len = self.bits.len();

        self.bits.extend(other.bits.iter().cloned());
        self.size += other.size;

        if leftover == 0 {
            return;
        }
        for i in len..self.bits.len() {
            self.move_bits(empty_bits, i);
        }
        if (self.size - 1) / BITS != self.bits.len() - 1 {
            self.bits.pop();
        }
    }

    fn check(&self, i: usize) {
        assert!(i < self.size,
                format!("Index out of bounds. Index: {} >= len: {}", i, self.size));
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    fn get(&self, i: usize) -> bool {
        self.check(i);
        (1 & (self.bits[i / BITS] >> (i % BITS))) != 0
    }

    fn put(&mut self, i: usize, bit: bool) {
        self.check(i);
        let (byte, bit_pos) = (i / BITS, i % BITS);
        self.bits[byte] &= !(1 << bit_pos);
        self.bits[byte] |= (bit as u8) << bit_pos;
    }

    fn move_bits(&mut self, bits: usize, i: usize) {
        let leftover = BITS - bits;
        let (from, to) = (self.bits[i], self.bits[i - 1]);
        self.bits[i - 1] = to ^ (from << leftover);
        self.bits[i] = from >> bits;
    }

    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> BitVectorIter<'a> {
        let itr = self.bits
            .iter()
            .flat_map(|byte| (0..BITS).map(move |i| ((byte >> i) & 1) != 0))
            .take(self.size);

        BitVectorIter { iter: Box::new(itr) }
    }

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.size
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    fn byte_len(&self) -> usize {
        self.bits.len()
    }
}

struct BitVectorIter<'a> {
    iter: Box<std::iter::Iterator<Item = bool> + 'a>,
}
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a BitVector {
    type Item = bool;
    type IntoIter = BitVectorIter<'a>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.iter()
    }
}
impl<'a> Iterator for BitVectorIter<'a> {
    type Item = bool;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}



pub trait HuffmanCompress {
    fn compress<T: std::io::Write>(&mut self, &mut T) -> Result<()>;
}

pub trait HuffmanDeCompress {
    fn de_compress<T: std::io::Write>(&mut self, writer: &mut T) -> Result<()> {
        let string = self.de_compress_to_string()?;
        writer.write_all(&string.as_bytes())?;
        Ok(())
    }
    fn de_compress_to_string(&mut self) -> Result<String>;
}

pub trait HuffmanCodes: HuffmanDeCompress + HuffmanCompress {}
impl<T: std::io::Read> HuffmanCodes for T {}
impl<T: std::io::Read> HuffmanCompress for T {
    fn compress<W: std::io::Write>(&mut self, writer: &mut W) -> Result<()> {
        let mut file_str = String::new();
        self.read_to_string(&mut file_str)?;
        let tree = HuffmanTree::new(&file_str)?;
        let encoded_file = tree.encode_string(&file_str);
        let junk = BITS - (encoded_file.len() % BITS);
        let mask = (((junk != BITS) as i8) << (BITS - 1)) >> (BITS - 1);

        tree.serialize(writer)?;
        writer.write_i8(junk as i8 & mask)?;
        writer.write(&encoded_file.bits)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl<T: std::io::Read> HuffmanDeCompress for T {
    fn de_compress_to_string(&mut self) -> Result<String> {
        let tree = HuffmanTree::de_serialize(self)?;
        let junk = self.read_i8()?;
        let mut bytes = Vec::new();
        self.read_to_end(&mut bytes)?;
        let bit_vec = BitVector {
            size: BITS * bytes.len() - junk as usize,
            bits: bytes,
        };
        let string = tree.decode_string(bit_vec.iter());
        Ok(string)
    }
}


pub fn encode<P, T>(path: P, target: T) -> Result<()>
    where P: AsRef<path::Path>,
          T: AsRef<path::Path>
{
    let f1 = fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(f1);
    let f2 = fs::File::create(target)?;
    let mut writer = io::BufWriter::new(f2);
    reader.compress(&mut writer)?;
    Ok(())
}

pub fn decode<P>(path: P) -> Result<String>
    where P: AsRef<path::Path>
{
    let f = fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = &mut io::BufReader::new(f);
    Ok(reader.de_compress_to_string()?)
}



fn read_file<P: AsRef<path::Path>>(path: P) -> std::io::Result<String> {
    let f = fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(f);
    let mut result = String::new();
    reader.read_to_string(&mut result)?;
    Ok(result)
}

fn rand_string(len: usize) -> String {
    use rand::Rng;
    rand::thread_rng()
        .gen_iter::<char>()
        .take(len)
        .collect()
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    for _ in 1..100 {
        let string = rand_string(5000);
        if let Err(err) = test(&string) {
            panic!(format!("{}", err))
        }
    }
}

fn test(text: &str) -> Result<()> {
    const FILE: &'static str = "test";
    const CFILE: &'static str = "compress";
    {
        let f = fs::File::create(FILE)?;
        let mut writer = io::BufWriter::new(f);
        writer.write_all(&text.as_bytes())?;
    }
    encode(FILE, CFILE)?;
    let x = decode(CFILE)?;
    let y = read_file(FILE)?;
    assert_eq!(x, y);
    assert_eq!(x, text);
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Combine imports like `io::Read` and `io::Write` with `use std::io::{Read, Write}`. In this case, consider using the IO prelude: `use std::io::prelude::*`.
2. You've intermixed test and production code, as well as test and production dependencies. This produces compile-time warnings (`` warning: function is never used: `read_file`, `rand_string`, `test` ``) and wastes end-user time during compilation and bandwidth during download.
3. I prefer to use a crate like quick-error to succinctly create error macros. I combined the description and display text where appropriate.
4. "frecuency" is misspelled; should be frequency.
5. It's idiomatic to use `|&foo| foo` instead of `|foo| *foo` when you can; generally `Copy` types allow this.
6. If you are creating and then throwing away the `HashMap`, just consume it during iteration to not have any references.
7. Prefer `match *foo { Foo:Variant => /* ... */ }` over `match foo { &Foo::Variant => /* ... */ }`. Same for `if let`.
8. Pattern match against `Some(true)` directly instead of using a match guard. I'd also explicitly say `Some(false)` as there are only the two cases.
9. Using `NativeEndian` is suspicious; that means the saved file will not be easily portable across different endian machines.
10. There's nothing wrong with using `reverse`, but you could just reverse the order of arguments to `cmp`.
11. I like to introduce a `key` method that `Eq`, `Ord`, `Hash`, etc. all use. This prevents them from drifting out of sync.
12. I ignored `BitVector` [as it has already been asked about in its own question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149519/bit-vector-implementation).
13. Decompress is usually written as one word with no separation.
14. `&string.as_bytes()` returns a `&&[u8]`, more references than needed. `string.as_bytes()` is sufficient.
15. The rand crate should be in `dev-dependencies` and only used within the test module or only included when `#[cfg(test)].
16. Generating a bunch of random strings feels like a *quickcheck* style test. I changed it, but the tests fail for strings containing `'\0'` `'\1'`, maybe more. These are valid characters, but the error is always `Empty`.
17. Avoid writing to files in a test. Files are slow compared to memory, and involving any external resources makes things harder. Since Rust tests run in parallel, as soon as you have a second test, you will have conflicts.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;
extern crate byteorder;

#[cfg(test)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate quickcheck;

use std::collections::hash_map::HashMap;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

use byteorder::{ReadBytesExt, WriteBytesExt, NativeEndian};
use std::{result, io, path, cmp, fs};

type Result<T> = result::Result<T, HuffmanError>;
const BITS: usize = 8;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum HuffmanError {
        Io(err: io::Error) {
            from()
            cause(err)
            description(err.description())
            display("IO error: {}", err)
        }
        ParseTree {
            description("Parse tree error: invalid encoded huffman tree")
        }
        AlphabetMismatch {
            description("Alphabet mismatch error: alphabet doesn't match parsed tree")
        }
        Empty {
            description("Empty stream")
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, Debug)]
enum HuffmanTree {
    Inner {
        frequency: u32,
        left: Box<HuffmanTree>,
        right: Box<HuffmanTree>,
    },
    Leaf { frequency: u32, character: char },
}

fn characters_mode(file: &str) -> HashMap<char, u32> {
    let mut table = HashMap::new();
    for c in file.chars() {
        *(table.entry(c).or_insert(0)) += 1;
    }
    table
}

fn create_priority_queue(input: &str) -> BinaryHeap<HuffmanTree> {
    characters_mode(input)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(c, f)| {
            HuffmanTree::Leaf {
                character: c,
                frequency: f,
            }
        })
        .collect()
}

impl HuffmanTree {
    fn new(input: &str) -> Result<HuffmanTree> {
        let mut pq = create_priority_queue(input);
        for _ in 1..pq.len() {
            let min1 = pq.pop().unwrap();
            let min2 = pq.pop().unwrap();
            pq.push(min1.join(min2));
        }
        pq.pop().ok_or(HuffmanError::Empty)
    }

    fn freq(&self) -> u32 {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match *self {
            Inner { frequency, .. } |
            Leaf { frequency, .. } => frequency,
        }
    }

    fn join(self, other: HuffmanTree) -> HuffmanTree {
        HuffmanTree::Inner {
            frequency: self.freq() + other.freq(),
            left: Box::new(self),
            right: Box::new(other),
        }
    }

    fn create_char_mapper_recur(&self,
                                bit_vec: &mut BitVector,
                                map: &mut HashMap<char, BitVector>) {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match *self {
            Inner { ref left, ref right, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(true);
                left.create_char_mapper_recur(bit_vec, map);
                bit_vec.push(false);
                right.create_char_mapper_recur(bit_vec, map);
            }
            Leaf { character, .. } => {
                map.insert(character, bit_vec.clone());
            }
        }
        bit_vec.pop();
    }

    fn create_char_mapper(&self) -> HashMap<char, BitVector> {
        let mut bit_vec = BitVector::new();
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        if let HuffmanTree::Leaf { .. } = *self {
            bit_vec.push(true);
        }
        self.create_char_mapper_recur(&mut bit_vec, &mut map);
        map
    }

    fn decode<I, T>(encoded_walk: &mut I, mut chars: &mut T) -> Result<HuffmanTree>
        where I: Iterator<Item = bool>,
              T: Iterator<Item = char>
    {
        match encoded_walk.next() {
            Some(true) => {
                let left = Self::decode(encoded_walk, chars)?;
                let right = Self::decode(encoded_walk, chars)?;
                Ok(left.join(right))
            }
            Some(false) => {
                let c = chars.next()
                    .ok_or(HuffmanError::AlphabetMismatch)?;
                Ok(HuffmanTree::Leaf {
                    frequency: 0,
                    character: c,
                })
            }
            None => Err(HuffmanError::ParseTree),
        }
    }

    fn serialize<W: std::io::Write>(&self, writer: &mut W) -> Result<()> {
        let (encoded_walk, alphabet) = self.encode();

        let walk_bit_len = encoded_walk.len() as u64;
        writer.write_u64::<NativeEndian>(walk_bit_len)?;
        writer.write(&encoded_walk.bits)?;

        let encoded_alphabet = alphabet.as_bytes();
        let alphabet_byte_len = encoded_alphabet.len() as u64;
        writer.write_u64::<NativeEndian>(alphabet_byte_len)?;
        writer.write_all(encoded_alphabet)?;

        Ok(())
    }

    fn de_serialize<R: std::io::Read>(reader: &mut R) -> Result<HuffmanTree> {
        use std::io::Read;

        let walk_len = reader.read_u64::<NativeEndian>()?;
        let mut walk_bytes = Vec::new();
        reader.take((walk_len + BITS as u64 - 1) / BITS as u64)
            .read_to_end(&mut walk_bytes)?;

        let bit_vec = BitVector {
            bits: walk_bytes,
            size: walk_len as usize,
        };

        let chars_len = reader.read_u64::<NativeEndian>()?;
        let mut chars = String::new();
        reader.take(chars_len)
            .read_to_string(&mut chars)?;

        let bit_iter = &mut bit_vec.iter();
        Self::decode(bit_iter, &mut chars.chars())
    }

    fn encode_recur(&self, bit_vec: &mut BitVector, alphabet: &mut String) {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match *self {
            Inner { ref left, ref right, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(true);
                left.encode_recur(bit_vec, alphabet);
                right.encode_recur(bit_vec, alphabet);
            }
            Leaf { character, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(false);
                alphabet.push(character);
            }
        }
    }

    fn encode(&self) -> (BitVector, String) {
        let mut bit_vector = BitVector::new();
        let mut alphabet = String::new();
        self.encode_recur(&mut bit_vector, &mut alphabet);
        (bit_vector, alphabet)
    }

    fn encode_string(&self, file_str: &str) -> BitVector {
        let char_map = self.create_char_mapper();
        let itr = file_str.chars()
            .map(|c| char_map.get(&c).expect("Assertion error"));

        let mut bit_vec = BitVector::new();
        for code in itr {
            bit_vec.append(&code);
        }
        bit_vec
    }

    fn decode_string<I>(&self, bit_iter: I) -> String
        where I: Iterator<Item = bool>
    {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        let mut node = self;
        let mut output = String::new();
        for bit in bit_iter {
            if let Inner { ref left, ref right, .. } = *node {
                node = if bit { left } else { right }
            }
            if let Leaf { character, .. } = *node {
                output.push(character);
                node = self;
            }
        }
        output
    }
}

impl Ord for HuffmanTree {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> cmp::Ordering {
        self.freq().cmp(&other.freq()).reverse()
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for HuffmanTree {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> Option<cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for HuffmanTree {
    fn eq(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> bool {
        self.freq() == other.freq()
    }
}

// BitVector elided

pub trait HuffmanCompress {
    fn compress<T: std::io::Write>(&mut self, &mut T) -> Result<()>;
}

pub trait HuffmanDeCompress {
    fn de_compress<T: std::io::Write>(&mut self, writer: &mut T) -> Result<()> {
        let string = self.de_compress_to_string()?;
        writer.write_all(string.as_bytes())?;
        Ok(())
    }
    fn de_compress_to_string(&mut self) -> Result<String>;
}

pub trait HuffmanCodes: HuffmanDeCompress + HuffmanCompress {}

impl<T: std::io::Read> HuffmanCodes for T {}

impl<T: std::io::Read> HuffmanCompress for T {
    fn compress<W: std::io::Write>(&mut self, writer: &mut W) -> Result<()> {
        let mut file_str = String::new();
        self.read_to_string(&mut file_str)?;
        let tree = HuffmanTree::new(&file_str)?;
        let encoded_file = tree.encode_string(&file_str);
        let junk = BITS - (encoded_file.len() % BITS);
        let mask = (((junk != BITS) as i8) << (BITS - 1)) >> (BITS - 1);

        tree.serialize(writer)?;
        writer.write_i8(junk as i8 & mask)?;
        writer.write(&encoded_file.bits)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl<T: std::io::Read> HuffmanDeCompress for T {
    fn de_compress_to_string(&mut self) -> Result<String> {
        let tree = HuffmanTree::de_serialize(self)?;
        let junk = self.read_i8()?;
        let mut bytes = Vec::new();
        self.read_to_end(&mut bytes)?;
        let bit_vec = BitVector {
            size: BITS * bytes.len() - junk as usize,
            bits: bytes,
        };
        let string = tree.decode_string(bit_vec.iter());
        Ok(string)
    }
}

pub fn encode<P, T>(path: P, target: T) -> Result<()>
    where P: AsRef<path::Path>,
          T: AsRef<path::Path>
{
    let f1 = fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(f1);
    let f2 = fs::File::create(target)?;
    let mut writer = io::BufWriter::new(f2);
    reader.compress(&mut writer)?;
    Ok(())
}

pub fn decode<P>(path: P) -> Result<String>
    where P: AsRef<path::Path>
{
    let f = fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = &mut io::BufReader::new(f);
    Ok(reader.de_compress_to_string()?)
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use quickcheck::TestResult;

    use std::{io, path, fs};
    use super::*;
    use std::io::prelude::*;

    fn read_file<P: AsRef<path::Path>>(path: P) -> io::Result<String> {
        let f = fs::File::open(path)?;
        let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(f);
        let mut result = String::new();
        reader.read_to_string(&mut result)?;
        Ok(result)
    }

    quickcheck! {
        fn prop(text: String) -> super::Result<TestResult> {
            // TODO: What is the appropriate invalid string set?
            if text.is_empty() {
                return Ok(TestResult::discard());
            }

            const FILE: &'static str = "test";
            const CFILE: &'static str = "compress";
            let f = fs::File::create(FILE)?;
            let mut writer = io::BufWriter::new(f);
            writer.write_all(text.as_bytes())?;

            encode(FILE, CFILE)?;
            let x = decode(CFILE)?;
            let y = read_file(FILE)?;

            // TODO: Should probably make these into two separate
            // tests for better error reporting.
            let eq = x == y && x == text;

            Ok(TestResult::from_bool(eq))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Bigger questions:

1. Why use `char` as the smallest unit instead of `u8`?
2. Why force the user to read the whole input all the way? If compressing a 2GiB file, I'd have to allocate 2GiB of memory! `new` and `encode` could stream data in and out, allowing the user to choose to allocate in one chunk or not.
3. Dealing with `File`s and `Path`s seems too specific and low-level for this library.