# Huffman encoding implementation -follow up

Tags: rust, compression

Follow up of this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150706/huffman-encoding-implementation-for-unicode/150953#150953).

I implemented most suggestions from the answers of the previous question.

Code:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;
extern crate byteorder;

#[cfg(test)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate quickcheck;

use std::collections::hash_map::HashMap;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use byteorder::{ReadBytesExt, WriteBytesExt, LittleEndian};
use std::{result, io, path, cmp, fs};
use std::io::prelude::*;

type Result<T> = result::Result<T, HuffmanError>;

const BITS: usize = 8;
const DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 8192;

macro_rules! try_opt {
    ($e:expr) =>(
        match $e {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(err) => return Some(Err(err)),
        }
    )
}

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum HuffmanError {
        Io(err: io::Error) {
            from()
            cause(err)
            description(err.description())
            display("IO error: {}", err)
        }
        ParseTree {
            description("Parse tree error: invalid encoded huffman tree")
        }
        AlphabetMismatch {
            description("Alphabet mismatch error: alphabet doesn't match parsed tree")
        }
        Empty {
            description("Empty stream")
        }
    }
}

struct DecodeBitIterator<'a> {
    root: &'a HuffmanTree,
    current: &'a HuffmanTree,
}

impl<'a> DecodeBitIterator<'a> {
    fn next(&mut self, bit: bool) -> Option<u8> {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        let (next, result) = match (self.root, self.current.next(bit)) {
            (_, Some(&Leaf { byte, .. })) |
            (&Leaf { byte, .. }, None) => (self.root, Some(byte)),

            (_, Some(inner)) => (inner, None),
            _ => panic!("assertion error"),
        };
        self.current = next;
        result
    }
}

fn create_mode_map<R: std::io::Read>(reader: &mut R,
                                     buffer_size: usize)
                                     -> Result<HashMap<u8, u32>> {
    let mut mode_map = HashMap::new();
    let mut buf = vec![0; buffer_size];
    loop {
        let size = reader.read(&mut buf)?;
        if size == 0 {
            break;
        }
        for &b in buf.iter().take(size) {
            *(mode_map.entry(b).or_insert(0)) += 1;
        }
    }
    Ok(mode_map)
}

fn iterate_bits<'a>(bits: &'a [u8], size: usize) -> BitVectorIter<'a> {
    let itr = bits.iter()
        .flat_map(|byte| (0..BITS).map(move |i| ((byte >> i) & 1) != 0))
        .take(size);

    BitVectorIter { iter: Box::new(itr) }
}


#[derive(Eq, Debug)]
pub enum HuffmanTree {
    Inner {
        frequency: u32,
        left: Box<HuffmanTree>,
        right: Box<HuffmanTree>,
    },
    Leaf { frequency: u32, byte: u8 },
}

impl HuffmanTree {
    pub fn new<R: std::io::Read>(reader: &mut R, buffer_size: usize) -> Result<HuffmanTree> {
        let mut pq: BinaryHeap<_> = create_mode_map(reader, buffer_size)
            ?
            .into_iter()
            .map(|(c, f)| {
                HuffmanTree::Leaf {
                    byte: c,
                    frequency: f,
                }
            })
            .collect();

        for _ in 1..pq.len() {
            let min1 = pq.pop().expect("assertion error");
            let min2 = pq.pop().expect("assertion error");
            pq.push(min1.join(min2));
        }
        pq.pop().ok_or(HuffmanError::Empty)
    }

    fn freq(&self) -> u32 {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match *self {
            Inner { frequency, .. } |
            Leaf { frequency, .. } => frequency,
        }
    }

    fn join(self, other: HuffmanTree) -> HuffmanTree {
        HuffmanTree::Inner {
            frequency: self.freq() + other.freq(),
            left: Box::new(self),
            right: Box::new(other),
        }
    }

    fn create_mapper_recur(&self, bit_vec: &mut BitVector, map: &mut HashMap<u8, BitVector>) {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match *self {
            Inner { ref left, ref right, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(true);
                left.create_mapper_recur(bit_vec, map);
                bit_vec.push(false);
                right.create_mapper_recur(bit_vec, map);
            }
            Leaf { byte, .. } => {
                map.insert(byte, bit_vec.clone());
            }
        }
        bit_vec.pop();
    }

    fn create_mapper(&self) -> HashMap<u8, BitVector> {
        let mut bit_vec = BitVector::new();
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        if let HuffmanTree::Leaf { .. } = *self {
            bit_vec.push(true);
        }
        self.create_mapper_recur(
            &mut bit_vec, 
            &mut map);
        map
    }

    fn decode<I, T>(encoded_walk: &mut I, mut bytes: &mut T) -> Result<HuffmanTree>
        where I: Iterator<Item = bool>,
              T: Iterator<Item = u8>
    {
        match encoded_walk.next() {
            Some(true) => {
                let left = Self::decode(encoded_walk, bytes)?;
                let right = Self::decode(encoded_walk, bytes)?;
                Ok(left.join(right))
            }
            Some(false) => {
                let c = bytes.next()
                    .ok_or(HuffmanError::AlphabetMismatch)?;
                Ok(HuffmanTree::Leaf {
                    frequency: 0,
                    byte: c,
                })
            }
            None => Err(HuffmanError::ParseTree),
        }
    }

    pub fn serialize<W: io::Write>(&self, writer: &mut W) -> Result<()> {
        let (encoded_walk, alphabet_bytes) = self.encode();

        let walk_bit_len = encoded_walk.len() as u64;
        writer.write_u64::<LittleEndian>(walk_bit_len)?;
        writer.write_all(&encoded_walk.bits)?;

        let alphabet_byte_len = alphabet_bytes.len() as u64;
        writer.write_u64::<LittleEndian>(alphabet_byte_len)?;
        writer.write_all(&alphabet_bytes)?;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn deserialize<R: io::Read>(reader: &mut R) -> Result<HuffmanTree> {
        let walk_bit_len = reader.read_u64::<LittleEndian>()?;
        let walk_byte_len = (walk_bit_len + BITS as u64 - 1) / BITS as u64;
        let mut walk_bytes = Vec::new();
        reader.take(walk_byte_len)
            .read_to_end(&mut walk_bytes)?;

        let alphabet_bytes_len = reader.read_u64::<LittleEndian>()?;
        let mut alphabet_bytes = Vec::new();
        reader.take(alphabet_bytes_len)
            .read_to_end(&mut alphabet_bytes)?;

        let bit_vec = BitVector {
            bits: walk_bytes,
            size: walk_bit_len as usize,
        };

        let bit_vec_iter = &mut bit_vec.iter();
        Self::decode(
            bit_vec_iter, 
            &mut alphabet_bytes.iter().cloned())
    }

    fn encode_recur(&self, bit_vec: &mut BitVector, alphabet_bytes: &mut Vec<u8>) {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match *self {
            Inner { ref left, ref right, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(true);
                left.encode_recur(bit_vec, alphabet_bytes);
                right.encode_recur(bit_vec, alphabet_bytes);
            }
            Leaf { byte, .. } => {
                bit_vec.push(false);
                alphabet_bytes.push(byte);
            }
        }
    }

    fn encode(&self) -> (BitVector, Vec<u8>) {
        let mut bit_vector = BitVector::new();
        let mut alphabet_bytes = Vec::new();
        self.encode_recur(&mut bit_vector, &mut alphabet_bytes);
        (bit_vector, alphabet_bytes)
    }

    fn decode_bit_iter<'a>(&'a self) -> DecodeBitIterator {
        DecodeBitIterator {
            root: self,
            current: self,
        }
    }

    pub fn encode_iter<'a, R: io::Read>(&self,
                                    reader: &'a mut R,
                                    buffer_size: usize)
                                    -> EncodeIterator<'a, R> {
        EncodeIterator {
            reader: reader,
            mapper: self.create_mapper(),
            buffer: vec![0u8; buffer_size],
        }
    }

    pub fn decode_iter<'a, 'b, R: io::Read>(&'b self,
                                        reader: &'a mut R,
                                        buffer_size: u64,
                                        bit_junk: usize)
                                        -> io::Result<DecodeIterator<'a, 'b, R>> {
        let mut last_buffer = Vec::new();
        reader.take(buffer_size)
            .read_to_end(&mut last_buffer)?;

        let itr = DecodeIterator {
            reader: reader,
            bit_mapper: self.decode_bit_iter(),
            buffer: Vec::new(),
            buffer_size: buffer_size,
            last_buffer: last_buffer,
            bit_junk: bit_junk,
        };
        Ok(itr)
    }

    fn next(&self, bit: bool) -> Option<&HuffmanTree> {
        use HuffmanTree::*;
        match *self {
            Inner { ref left, .. } if bit => Some(left),
            Inner { ref right, .. } => Some(right),
            Leaf { .. } => None,
        }
    }
}

pub struct EncodeIterator<'a, R: io::Read + 'a> {
    reader: &'a mut R,
    mapper: HashMap<u8, BitVector>,
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
}

impl<'a, R: io::Read> Iterator for EncodeIterator<'a, R> {
    type Item = io::Result<BitVector>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let size = try_opt!(self.reader.read(&mut self.buffer));
        if size == 0 {
            return None;
        }
        let mut bit_vec = BitVector::new();
        let itr = self.buffer
            .iter()
            .take(size)
            .map(|c| {
                self.mapper
                    .get(&c)
                    .expect("assertion error")
            });

        for code in itr {
            bit_vec.append(&code);
        }
        Some(Ok(bit_vec))
    }
}

pub struct DecodeIterator<'a, 'b, R: io::Read + 'a> {
    reader: &'a mut R,
    bit_mapper: DecodeBitIterator<'b>,
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
    buffer_size: u64,
    last_buffer: Vec<u8>,
    bit_junk: usize,
}

impl<'a, 'b, R: io::Read> Iterator for DecodeIterator<'a, 'b, R> {
    type Item = io::Result<Vec<u8>>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        fn bool_mask(b: bool) -> usize {
            (((b as i32) << 31) >> 31) as usize
        }
        let size = try_opt!(self.reader
            .take(self.buffer_size)
            .read_to_end(&mut self.buffer));

        if size == 0 
            && self.last_buffer.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }
        let bit_len = BITS * self.last_buffer.len() 
                        - (bool_mask(size == 0) 
                            & self.bit_junk);                       
        let mut bytes = Vec::new();
        for bit in iterate_bits(&self.last_buffer, bit_len) {
            let byte = match self.bit_mapper.next(bit) {
                Some(byte) => byte,
                None => continue,
            };
            bytes.push(byte);
        }
        std::mem::swap(
            &mut self.buffer, 
            &mut self.last_buffer);
        self.buffer.clear();
        Some(Ok(bytes))
    }
}

impl Ord for HuffmanTree {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> cmp::Ordering {
        self.freq().cmp(&other.freq()).reverse()
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for HuffmanTree {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> Option<cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for HuffmanTree {
    fn eq(&self, other: &HuffmanTree) -> bool {
        self.freq() == other.freq()
    }
}

pub trait HuffmanCompress {
    fn compress<T>(&mut self, writer: &mut T) -> Result<()>
        where T: io::Write + io::Seek
    {
        self.compress_with_buffer_size(writer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    }
    fn compress_with_buffer_size<T>(&mut self, &mut T, buffer: usize) -> Result<()>
        where T: io::Write + io::Seek;
}

pub trait HuffmanDeCompress {
    fn decompress<T>(&mut self, writer: &mut T) -> Result<()>
        where T: io::Write
    {
        self.decompress_with_buffer_size(writer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE as u64)
    }
    fn decompress_with_buffer_size<T>(&mut self, writer: &mut T, buffer_size: u64) -> Result<()>
        where T: io::Write;
}

pub trait HuffmanCodes: HuffmanDeCompress + HuffmanCompress {}

impl<T: io::Read + io::Seek> HuffmanCodes for T {}

impl<T: io::Read + io::Seek> HuffmanCompress for T {
    fn compress_with_buffer_size<W>(&mut self, writer: &mut W, buffer_size: usize) -> Result<()>
        where W: io::Write + io::Seek
    {
        use std::io::SeekFrom;
        let tree = HuffmanTree::new(self, buffer_size)?;
        tree.serialize(writer)?;
        self.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0))?;
        let pos = writer.seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))?;
        writer.write_i8(0)?;
        let mut bit_vec = BitVector::new();
        for code in tree.encode_iter(self, buffer_size) {
            bit_vec.append(&code?);
            let bit_leftover = bit_vec.len() % BITS;
            let leftover = (bit_leftover != 0) as usize;
            let byte_len = bit_vec.byte_len();
            writer.write_all(&bit_vec.bits[0..byte_len - leftover])?;
            bit_vec.bits.swap(0, byte_len - 1);
            bit_vec.bits.truncate(leftover);
            bit_vec.size = bit_leftover;
        }
        writer.write_all(&bit_vec.bits)?;
        let junk = BITS - bit_vec.len() % BITS;
        let mask = (((junk != BITS) as i8) << (BITS - 1)) >> (BITS - 1);
        let current = writer.seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))?;
        writer.seek(SeekFrom::Start(pos))?;
        writer.write_i8(junk as i8 & mask)?;
        writer.seek(SeekFrom::Start(current))?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl<T: std::io::Read> HuffmanDeCompress for T {
    fn decompress_with_buffer_size<W>(&mut self, writer: &mut W, buffer_size: u64) -> Result<()>
        where W: io::Write
    {
        let tree = HuffmanTree::deserialize(self)?;
        let junk = self.read_i8()? as usize;

        for bytes in tree.decode_iter(self, buffer_size, junk)? {
            writer.write_all(&bytes?)?
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub fn io_map<P, T, F>(path: P, target: T, mapping_function: F) -> Result<()>
    where P: AsRef<path::Path>,
          T: AsRef<path::Path>,
          F: Fn(&mut io::BufReader<fs::File>, &mut io::BufWriter<fs::File>) -> Result<()>
{

    let f1 = fs::File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(f1);
    let f2 = fs::File::create(target)?;
    let mut writer = io::BufWriter::new(f2);
    mapping_function(&mut reader, &mut writer)?;
    Ok(())
}

pub fn decode<P, T>(path: P, target: T) -> Result<()>
    where P: AsRef<path::Path>,
          T: AsRef<path::Path>
{
    io_map(path, target, |r, w| r.decompress(w))
}

pub fn encode<P, T>(path: P, target: T) -> Result<()>
    where P: AsRef<path::Path>,
          T: AsRef<path::Path>
{
    io_map(path, target, |r, w| r.compress(w))
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct BitVector {
    bits: Vec<u8>,
    size: usize,
}

impl BitVector {
    pub fn new() -> BitVector {
        BitVector {
            bits: Vec::new(),
            size: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, bit: bool) {
        let leftover = self.size % BITS;
        if leftover == 0 {
            self.bits.push(0);
        }
        let last_byte = self.bits
            .last_mut()
            .expect("Assertion error");

        *last_byte |= (bit as u8) << leftover;
        self.size += 1;
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn clear(&mut self) {
        self.bits.clear();
        self.size = 0;
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) {
        if self.len() == 0 {
            return;
        }
        let len = self.size - 1;
        self.put(len, false);
        self.size = len;
        if self.len() % BITS == 0 {
            self.bits.pop();
        }
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn push_all(&mut self, bits: &[bool]) {
        for bit in bits {
            self.push(*bit);
        }
    }

    pub fn append(&mut self, other: &BitVector) {
        let leftover = self.size % BITS;
        let empty_bits = BITS - leftover;
        let len = self.bits.len();

        self.bits.extend(other.bits.iter().cloned());
        self.size += other.size;

        if leftover == 0 {
            return;
        }
        for i in len..self.bits.len() {
            self.move_bits(empty_bits, i);
        }
        if (self.size - 1) / BITS != self.bits.len() - 1 {
            self.bits.pop();
        }
    }

    pub fn check(&self, i: usize) {
        assert!(i < self.size,
                format!("Index out of bounds. Index: {} >= len: {}", i, self.size));
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn get(&self, i: usize) -> bool {
        self.check(i);
        (1 & (self.bits[i / BITS] >> (i % BITS))) != 0
    }

    pub fn put(&mut self, i: usize, bit: bool) {
        self.check(i);
        let (byte, bit_pos) = (i / BITS, i % BITS);
        self.bits[byte] &= !(1 << bit_pos);
        self.bits[byte] |= (bit as u8) << bit_pos;
    }

    fn move_bits(&mut self, bits: usize, i: usize) {
        let leftover = BITS - bits;
        let (from, to) = (self.bits[i], self.bits[i - 1]);
        self.bits[i - 1] = to ^ (from << leftover);
        self.bits[i] = from >> bits;
    }

    pub fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> BitVectorIter<'a> {
        iterate_bits(&self.bits, self.size)
    }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.size
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.size == 0
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn byte_len(&self) -> usize {
        self.bits.len()
    }
}

pub struct BitVectorIter<'a> {
    iter: Box<std::iter::Iterator<Item = bool> + 'a>,
}
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a BitVector {
    type Item = bool;
    type IntoIter = BitVectorIter<'a>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.iter()
    }
}
impl<'a> Iterator for BitVectorIter<'a> {
    type Item = bool;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}
```

Test:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use quickcheck::TestResult;

    use std::io;
    use super::*;
    use std::io::prelude::*;

    fn read_stream<W: io::Read>(reader: &mut W) -> io::Result<String> {
        let mut result = String::new();
        reader.read_to_string(&mut result)?;
        Ok(result)
    }
    quickcheck! {
        fn prop(text: String) -> super::Result<TestResult> {
            if text.is_empty() {
                return Ok(TestResult::discard());
            }
            let mut mock_input_stream =  io::Cursor::new(text.into_bytes());
            let mut mock_compress_stream = io::Cursor::new(Vec::new());
            let mut mock_decompress_stream = io::Cursor::new(Vec::new());

            mock_input_stream.compress(&mut mock_compress_stream)?;
            mock_compress_stream.seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(0))?;
            mock_compress_stream.decompress(&mut mock_decompress_stream)?;
            mock_input_stream.seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(0))?;
            mock_decompress_stream.seek(io::SeekFrom::Start(0))?;

            let expected = read_stream(&mut mock_input_stream)?;
            let test = read_stream(&mut mock_decompress_stream)?;
            Ok(TestResult::from_bool(expected == test))
        }
    }
}
```